# How do I get npm start to open a specific profile on Chrome?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-start

I have a separate Chrome profile to do development work in.

When I run `npm start` it opens my default Chrome profile.

I'd like it to open my development profile.

I've tried creating a `.env` file in the root of the project with the following in it

```
REACT_APP_BROWSER=chrome
REACT_APP_BROWSER_ARGS=--profile-directory="Profile 1"
```

installing `env-cmd` and changing the start command in the scripts section of the `package.json` file

```
"start": "env-cmd .env npm react-scripts start",
```

but when I run `npm start` I get the following error:

```
alex@Alex-PC:~/code/udemy/grider/pics$ npm start

> pics@0.1.0 start /home/alex/code/udemy/grider/pics
> env-cmd .env npm react-scripts start

spawn .env ENOENT
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 130
npm ERR! pics@0.1.0 start: `env-cmd .env npm react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 130
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the pics@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/alex/.npm/_logs/2020-12-04T22_27_25_381Z-debug.log
```

Am I even on the right track or have I went in completely the wrong direction?

Comment: did the answer below help?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for any additional libraries. It seems you are using react and `react-scripts` is already using `dotenv` as it can be seen [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/#adding-development-environment-variables-in-env). This also means that there is no addition needed to start script: `"start": "react-scripts start"`.

Using dotenv you can just create a .env file in your root directory with the following options as it can be seen from [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/advanced-configuration/).

**.env**

```
BROWSER=google-chrome
BROWSER_ARGS=--profile-directory="Profile 1"
```

Note: `google-chrome` on Linux / `chrome` on Windows for the `BROWSER` variable

**BUT** the **ISSUE** with this seems to be that because of the space in the profile name, it will only be passed the part before the space. Chrome uses an internal profile name for the profile directory and by default creates the internal profile name with space in them.

There does not seem to be a way to pass the profile name with spaces in it (no matter if using quotes/escaped quotes/additional variables etc.) but I really hope I will stand corrected on this issue.

A **WORKAROUND** to the spacing issue:  Create a new profile name without space. This will happen automatically if you just run `npm start` and the profile name you assigned in the `.env` file does not match any of the ones already in your browser. Afterwards just sync your account in it and use it as normal.